# Заключить слова в кавычки в строке Си

Tags: c, массивы, строки, char

Необходимо все вхождения слова заключить в ". Я нахожу вхождения, но не понимаю, как можно вставить символ. Допустим, есть строка: `abc Hello abc world abc`, после обработки она должна иметь вид: `"abc" Hello "abc" world "abc"`. Я с помощью `strstr()` нахожу вхождения, но не понимаю, как дальше обработать. Использовать чистый Си. Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>



int main(void)
{
    
    char* c1;
    char s1[] = "abc Heabcllo woabcrld";
    char* buff[] = " ";
    for (c1 = strstr(s1, "abc"); c1; c1 = strstr(s1, "abc")) {
        //Здесь добавление символа
    }
        
    printf("%s\n", buff);
}
```

Comment: Переписывайте в другой буфер, в котором имеется достаточно места.

Comment: @Harry Это динамический массив создать? Или как? Извините, еще не силен в этом.

Comment: Можно динамический, можно статический — лишь бы места хватало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, например... не очень красиво, но работает, а на ночь глядя более красивое изобретать не тянет :)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "abc Heabcllo woabcrld";
    char a[] = "abc";
    int count = 0;
    for(char * c = strstr(s,a); c; c = strstr(c+strlen(a),a)) ++count;

    char *buf = malloc(strlen(s) + count*2 + 1);
    strcpy(buf,s);
    for(char * c = strstr(buf,a); c; c = strstr(c+strlen(a),a))
    {
        memmove(c+strlen(a)+2,c+strlen(a),strlen(c+strlen(a))+1);
        *c = '\"';
        strcpy(c+1,a);
        *(c+strlen(a)+1) = '\"';
    }
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    free(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Считаем "старые" фрагменты, выделяем буфер, копируем строку по кусочкам, заменяя "старые" фрагменты на "новые":

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *replace_all(const char *text, const char *old, const char *new) {
    const int n = strlen(old);
    const int m = strlen(new);

    int count = 0;
    for (const char *c = strstr(text, old); c != NULL; c = strstr(c + n, old)) {
        ++count;
    }

    char *result = malloc(strlen(text) + count * (m - n) + 1);
    if (result == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    const char *c = text;
    char *d = result;
    for (; ; ) {
        const char *c1 = strstr(c, old);
        if (c1 == NULL) {
            strcpy(d, c);
            break;
        }
        const int k = c1 - c;
        memcpy(d, c, k);
        c = c1;
        d += k;
        memcpy(d, new, m);
        c += n;
        d += m;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    {
        char *result = replace_all("abc Heabcllo woabcrld", "abc", "\"abc\"");
        printf("%s\n", result);
        free(result);
    }
    {
        char *result = replace_all("abc Heabcllo woabcrld", "abc", "");
        printf("%s\n", result);
        free(result);
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror replace_all.c && ./a.out 
> "abc" He"abc"llo wo"abc"rld
>  Hello world
> ```